# Is there any way to specify a JSON response when listing buckets from Amazon s3?

Tags: json, api, amazon-s3, response

After reading the API docs it seems that you can only list buckets from S3 in XML.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html

Since S3 is a websevicey service, surely there must be a way to do this in JSON? Or are you in fact stuck with XML?

Answer (score -2):

I just found this, which might help

http://shrub.appspot.com/

-John

Comment: Link not working. When adding a link answer, please add some content from that link so that when it's not available, the content will be still here.